# Javascript+Highcharts: Substituting series.data for my own

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been doing this script for a volunteering university-site job.

Please ignore all parameters apart from **wattages** and **schools**. Those are SQL result sets that have been converted to arrays using **json_encode()**. Result sets have Strings as values, I believe, so both `wattages` and `schools` should be arrays of strings.

What I want to do is input my own `data` for the pie graph, in this case **mySeries**, which I build/fill up at the start and put as `data` later.

```
function createPieChartGradient(data,title,xlabel,ylabel,type,step,div_id,wattages,schools){

    var float_watt = new Array();
    for(var index = 0; index < wattages.length; index++)
    {
        float_watt[index] = parseFloat(wattages[index]).toFixed(2);
    }

    var mySeries = [];  //Hopefully this creates a [String, number] array that can be used as Data.
    for (var i = 0; i < float_watt.length; i++) {
        mySeries.push([schools[i], float_watt[i]]);
    }

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graph',
            zoomType: 'x',
            defaultSeriesType: type
        },
        title: {
                text: 'Consumption Percentage of IHU Schools, Last 7 days'
            },
        tooltip: {
            //pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
           // maxZoom: 20 * 1000,
            title: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '14px'
            },
                text: xlabel
            },
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                step: step,
                align: 'right'//,
            //  step: temp
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '14px'
            },
                text: ylabel
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                formatter: function() {
                    return parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            min: 0
        },
        legend: {
             layout: 'vertical',
             align: 'right',
             verticalAlign: 'center',
             floating: true,
             shadow: true
          },

        series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Consumption Percentage',
                    data: mySeries       //Problematic line.
                }]                                                                                      //Faculty with the smallest wattage -> Green.
    };  //end of var options{}                                                                          //Next: -> Yellow.
                                                                                                        //Last -> Red.
    //Draw the chart.
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);                                                          //TODO: Change colours.
    document.write("FINISHED");
}
```

The thing is, the above won't work. Since I'm not using an environment (writing in notepad++ and testing on my apache web server, via the results) I have manually aliminated the **problematic line to be `data: mySeries`.**

Any idea why that is? Aren't they the same type of array, `[String, number]`?

Additionally, are there any environments that will help me debug javascript programs? I'm really at my wit's end with this situation and I'd very much prefer to have an IDE tell me what's wrong, or at least point me at the right direction.

Comment: have you tried dumping the contents of mySeries to ensure your assumptions are correct? e.g., console.log(mySeries)

Comment: @Corey I used multiple `document.write()`s at key points, tons of them, and it checked out. mySeries printed 3 schools and 3 wattages, which were the sizes of these arrays.

Comment: Use console.log() instead of document.write() when debugging. You can see the output in the Chrome Javascript console. Plus, objects that are logged can be navigated. It will make your life much easier. (Though make sure you remove them before you ship. IE only exposes the console object when the debugger is open.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see where you are calling "toFixed"? Let's run a small experiment:

```
var wattages = [2.0, 3.0];

 var float_watt = new Array();
 for(var index = 0; index < wattages.length; index++)
 {
    float_watt[index] = parseFloat(wattages[index]).toFixed(2);
 }

 console.log(JSON.stringify(float_watt));
```

The output is not what you expect:

```
["2.00", "3.00"]
```

See how it got converted to a string? If you delete the "toFixed" and let your formatter do its job, things will go just fine.

EDIT

Here's how you fix your formatter:

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2);
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

The yLabels formatter is doing nothing for the pie.

Comment: God, you're a lifesaver. Thanks a lot.

The toFixed() call was to get only the two decimal digits as the wattages are averaged out and I tend to get pretty large floats as a result, for example `522.22222222`.

Comment: I've added code to correctly format the numbers into the answer. It goes at the top level of your configuration, in the same object as "xAxis" and "yAxis". Hope that helps! (Don't forget to click the "answered" button if that closes it out.)

Comment: One more thing before I test it out, where does `console.log()` output its contents?

Comment: Open Chrome, click the hamburger tray (the three bars on the right), and click "Tools" and "Javascript console". Here's an article:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Firefox has a similar "Web Debugging Console" and even IE now supports it when you press F12.

Comment: I apologise for all the questions, I'm absolutely a virgin when it comes to Javascript, not to mention plots, and you've been extremely helpful so far.

Where does the `plotOptions:{}` go and how does it set the format for the series.data field?

Comment: Put it right after tooltip {...}, and right before xAxis {...}. The formatter function will be called by highcharts to convert the number into a string for display. That is your opportunity to screw it up as much as you like. (e.g. You could make it say "banana" instead of a number!) Just be aware that the two values (label and number) are mapped to this.x and this.y. Don't worry about why. There are internal highcharts reasons for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45959/discussion-between-dimitris-sfounis-and-64bitbob)